# macports: bash_completion not working with make (with gmake or without)

Tags: bash, macports

I've installed `bash_completion` from `macports`. Completion works fine for `git`, for instance, where I installed `+bash_completion` variant.

Completion doesn't work for `make`, whether I install `macports'` `gmake` or not. `gmake` doesn't even have `+bash_completion` variant.

How do I make it work?

Comment: How should it work?

Comment: The way it works on Linux: complete makefile targets after 'make ' <tab>.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I didn't follow `bash` installation instructions. On a fresh system, after adding `bash` to `/etc/shells` and `chsh -s /opt/local/bin/bash`, it worked.